# MFMailComposeViewController : exit on cancel

Tags: iphone, email

i have the following code presenting the user with email from within the app :

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
[picker setSubject:@"Subject"];
NSString* link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href='%@'>Report</a>",link];
[picker setMessageBody:link isHTML:YES];
picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault; 
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

and allso :

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error{ 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

everything works just fine , expect that i'd like the cancel to skip the delete draft/save draft/cancel stage and basicly chose the delete draft (not present it to the user) 
can this be done ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *) controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult) result error:(NSError *)error
    {
        switch (result) {
            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
                break;

            case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
                break;

            case MFMailComposeResultSent:
                break;

            case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        //Dismiss the mailViewController.
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Is this what you are looking for? You can then handle each error or completion individually!